# MPDF colsum is not displaying table columns sum in table footer

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using mpdf in laravel. But it is not displaying {colsum} in the table footer. using Laravel PDF: mPDF wrapper for Laravel 5.

[image]

controller code to pass data to view file.

```
 $data = [
        'data' => $vochur,
        'date' => date('m/d/Y H:i:s A'),
        'setting' => $setting,
        'user' => Auth::user()->first_name
    ];


    $pdf = PDFF::loadView('pdf.vouchers', $data);
```

view file code. using

```
       <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>{colsum}</td>
                <td>{colsum}</td>
                <td>{colsum}</td>
                <td>{colsum}</td>
                <td>{colsum}</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>

            @foreach ($data['bilties'] as $key => $item)

                <tr>
                    <td>{{$item['id']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item['customer']['name']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item['product_type']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item['quantity']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item['fare']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item['labour']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item['adv']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item['total']}}</td>
                </tr>

            @endforeach
        </tbody>
```

Comment: No one can help you unless you provide your HTML code. And people will have less enthusiasm helping you when you spam your question to all thinkable channels.

Comment: yes provided please check now.

Comment: This HTML code is not exactly reproducible without providing $data['bilties']. When I try this with static numbers, everything works correctly - verify that the templating system does not mangle the braces, eg. by HTML encoding.

Comment: Actually, the issue was with the font family. fixed thanks for your reply.

Comment: Then please either remove this question or write a summary of the solution and self-approve it to mark this as resolved.